# Как правильно очистить textBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет, в процессе изучения C#, возник вопрос, по поводу очистки textBox с WinForms.
На просторах встречаются, разные способы:

```
textBox.Text = null;
textBox.Clear();
textBox.Text = "";
```

Какой правильнее использовать? Может есть какие-то особенности?
Спасибо.

Comment: Откуда этот текстбокс: WinForms, WPF, что-то ещё? | Вообще, если следовать шаблонам MVC/MVVM и т. п., то контрол должен быть привязан к модели (свойству модели данных). Следовательно, очищать нужно это свойство, а контрол (в нашем случае текстбокс), очистится сам.

Comment: textBox с WinForms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мое мнение -- плевать как ты будешь очищать) Любым из этих способов.

но раз уж есть функция `textBox.Clear();` то я бы пользовался бы ею. Как минимум -- потому что короче запись и читабельнее код.

Answer (score 2):

Если проследить цепочку вызовов свойства `Text` [1](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBox.cs,98b5645df3380796), [2](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,2a709215c270dcea), [3](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,952c66876790b53a), то мы увидим следующий код:

```
if (value == null) {
    value = "";
}
```

То есть `null` задать этому свойству невозможно, всё равно будет присвоена пустая строка. Следовательно, способ `textBox.Text = null;` отпадает.

Проследив цепочку вызовов метода `Clear` [4](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolStripTextBox.cs,dbbc05cc07bef802), [5](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,e0168a49262d4536), видим:

```
public void Clear() {
    Text = null;
}
```

Внезапно, присвоение `null`. Мда, почему бы сразу не присваивать `""`?..

Вообще, используйте метод, раз уж он есть и вызов его на пару символов короче.

---

В современных приложениях обычно используется [привязка данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding). Напрямую мы не работаем с графическими контролами. Значения в них меняются опосредованно.

Пример получается громоздкий, но раз уж взялся объяснять, то доведу дело до конца.

Допустим, у нас имеется класс, описывающий человека, у которого есть имя (другие свойства добавьте сами). Чтобы экземпляры этого класса могли участвовать в двусторонней привязке данных, нужно реализовать у него интерфейс [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface).

```
class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;

        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Создадим экземпляр этого класса и прибиндим его к имеющемуся текстбоксу:

```
var person = new Person { Name = "Bob" };

textBox.DataBindings.Add(
    nameof(TextBox.Text), person, nameof(Person.Name), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Теперь для очистки текстбокса достаточно очистить привязанное свойство:

```
person.Name = "";
```

Если вы будете создавать большие серьёзные приложения, то неизбежно столкнётесь с data binding и INotifyPropertyChanged, поэтому придётся их освоить.